# Ionic v3 align button and icon

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

When creating a button on the [ionic creator(v3)](https://creator.ionic.io/) I can create a button like this

[image]

But when I export the template it renders like so:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<button ion-button icon-end block color="energized">
      <span>Edit</span>
      <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

How do I correctly align the button and icon so that the icon is positioned at the end and the button text is centered. Is there a built in way I can do this using ionic directives? Or do I have to create custom CSS to achieve this?

Comment: Do not post images, post code instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From css, you can add

```
button ion-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Selector can be `button[icon-end][block] ion-icon{...}`